# Can you find the 2 words and solve this puzzle?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

Answer to this puzzle consists of two words that are related to the game Old School RuneScape:

[image: Puzzle image here]

Comment: Are these dots somehow related to rot 13(Oenvyyr fpevcg)???

Comment: @LakshaySura I do think so, as they spell rot13(bterf).

Comment: @Ardweaden is any giant eating man there in this game??

Comment: @vealgrapes wanna give us a hint to steer us in right direction??

Answer (score 2):

No comments mentioned these points,and sorry I can't comment because I have less than 50 points. The dots look like braille, and the characters left to right top to bottom are as follows: S,R,M,O,and E. These letters form an anagram for the word Morse. Interestingly enough, the first two letters in the name of the image are the letters Cw , which is a term used to denote Morse transmissions(Carrier Wave or Continuous Wave).

Comment: Look at the two 9 s it is like lvl 99

Comment: You are probably right but I can't see anything which needs to be decoded from Morse code.

Comment: @Deepthinker101 lvl 99 is somehow related to rot 13(Fxvyypncr) though I don't know about this since I have not played this game.

Comment: And I have mentioned about Braille in my comment.

Comment: Also, it's possible those "9's" could be gs, I couldn't find the font so I can't be certain

Comment: @Lakshay Sura oh! I read you comment as "Are the dots somehow related to rot 13?", my fault

Comment: No problem @Kyle Jon it happens sometimes. If you think they are "g" can you make something out of it.